# Different results in swi-prolog and yap

Tags: prolog, compatibility, swi-prolog, iso-prolog, yap-prolog

The sample program enumerates and counts the number of 8-queen solutions. (sorry if the code is hard to read; this is machine-generated from an S-expression. The original code is https://www.cpp.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/2_11.html)

rules:

```
[user].
(perm([X|Y],Z) :- (perm(Y,W),takeout(X,Z,W))).
perm([],[]).
takeout(X,[X|R],R).
(takeout(X,[F|R],[F|S]) :- (takeout(X,R,S))).
(solve(P) :- (perm([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],P),combine([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],P,S,D),alldiff(S),alldiff(D))).
(combine([X1|X],[Y1|Y],[S1|S],[D1|D]) :- (is(S1,+(X1,Y1)),is(D1,-(X1,Y1)),combine(X,Y,S,D))).
combine([],[],[],[]).
(alldiff([X|Y]) :- (\+ member(X,Y),alldiff(Y))).
alldiff([X]).
end_of_file.
```

query:

```
(setof(P,solve(P),Set),length(Set,L),write(L),write('\n'),fail).
```

swipl returns 92; while yap returns 40320.
Also, when I query `solve(P)`, swipl only returns two solutions (which also contradicts 92); yap returns much more (possibly 40320 of them). So why the difference? Is there such a serious compatibility issue?

Versions:

- YAP 6.2.2 (x86_64-linux): Sat Sep 17 13:59:03 UTC 2016
- SWI-Prolog version 7.2.3 for amd64

Comment: Could you still put the code into a readable form?

Comment: there is the original one in the link

Comment: Next time, please to include here the readable version. That's the way SO works.

Comment: I was afraid since the original code does not belong to me, and the license was unclear.

Comment: I don't think the license applies to the formatting. It applies to the content.

Comment: SWI Provided 92 solutions when I tried it. You must have done something wrong in that case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In older versions of YAP, a query for an undefined predicate simply failed. In the case above, it is `member/2` which is not defined in YAP.  And for this reason your test `alldif/1` always succeeds - thus the large number you get.

The behavior for this is governed by the Prolog flag `unknown` whose default value should be `error`.  In YAP 6.2 the default was (incorrectly) `fail`. This was corrected in 6.3. Say

```
:- set_prolog_flag(unknown, error).
```

to get a clean error for undefined predicates. Then, you would need to define [`member/2`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#member).

Comment: thank you, so `member` is not the built-ins... but those "prologues" (compatibility layer, sort of) sounds good. I can make the lisp-to-prolog library to load it whenever the process is launched.

Comment: hmm, by the way, just cloned yap 6.3.3, after the `.configure` it doesn't build because of `make: *** No rule to make target 'H/dglobals.h', needed by 'yap'.  Stop.` ...

Comment: Wondering why the standardization is going so bad compared to the other CSP community. Minizinc is a common format in CSP and is doing the competition annually. SAT has DIMACS and SMT has one as well.

Comment: @Asai: The transition from 6.2->6.3 is rather a case of confluence.